# Navigation property without foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have entities:

```
[Table("Currency")]
public class Currency
{
    [Key]
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public char Symbol { get; set; }
}

[Table("Invoice")]
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    // public virtual ICollection<Currency> CurrencyList { get; set; }
}
```

I need every invoice to contain all possible currencies that are in the database. If I just set navigation property as in the commented line, then the system tries to implicitly create its own foreign key constraint that doesnt actually exists and then gives an error.
Is there a way to make that navigational prop with no FK?

Comment: If you want to *always* get all currencies for the invoice, wouldn't it be easier to have a helper (static) method which would return that list. You could even do some caching in that method to avoid hitting the DB table for currencies every time you look up an invoice.

Comment: @carlosfigueira yes, I need it always, but i need is as property of Invoice...

Comment: If you really need it, you can implement it as a get-only property which calls that method.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I dont think it's a good idea to put methods inside EF code first entities, especially those who affects DbContext

Comment: I agree, which is why I suggested an external method. You're trying to use a relationship in an EF code first where such relationship does not exist. Since you really need (make sure that there are no other options before going this path, though) to have that "pseudo-relationship", you can declare on your context that the property will be ignored and not mapped to the database (use the `OnModelCreating` method in the `DbContext` and do something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().Ignore(i => i.CurrencyList)`.

Comment: I have to say, I am curious. Why do you want to list ALL currencies, when your data model shows that there is a specific currency ID associated with an invoice...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a navigation property is what you're looking for.  this msdn article discusses navigation properties more in depth, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Every object can have a navigation property for every relationship in which it participates.

this sentence specifically and the two sections Modifying Relationships and Navigating Relationships point more to the fact that these properties are specifically for EF relationships, if there is no relationship between the two objects there likely shouldn't be a navigation property.

@carlosfiguira has a good idea about a helper class, which i agree with.  but hearing your issues with adding helper code to your CodeFirst models.

My suggestion would be to create a composite model that has an invoice property and the list of currencies.  I've done this before especially in Web patterns, that type of complex object might be called a ViewModel depending on use case.